# removed laptop from domain and lost access to admin account

Tags: windows-vista

I just removed my vista laptop from domain, but now I cannot login in with local administrator as local admin account is disabled. I have only local user account that works.

What can I do  to get admin rights back?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to boot from a Rescue is Possible (RIP) Linux disc, mount the hard drive, change into /mnt/mountpoint/WINDOWS/system32/config (or wherever your particular version of Windows is holding the SAM file), then run "chntpw ./SAM"

That application I believe has the ability to enable the account as well as wipe the password. I don't change the password, I just wipe it and reboot to Windows to re-set the password.

You should be able to find the SAM file from your in-Windows user account before trying it so you can get the proper path.

Answer (score 1):

I use NT Offline Password Recovery to reset passwords and enable accounts on NT-based systems. If you just read the prompts it's pretty straight-forward.

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Answer (score -1):

If either of those bother you, or fill you with fear, then add the computer back to the domain, and then enable and reset the local admin account that way.

Comment: Don't you need to be a local administrator to make changes (such as join it to the domain)...?

Comment: Oh ... shoot! (Feels stupid) Ignore my comment! My mind most def was somewhere else. Thanks Dan for correcting me :)